# Анализ производительности жёсткого диска

Tags: производительность, железо, диск

Есть результат анализа двухнедельной давности

[image: Старый скриншот sda]

и сейчас

[image: Новый скриншот sda]

Видно, что средняя скорость уменьшилась со 169.7 до 166.2, а время доступа увеличилось с 14.57 до 14.98. Если наложить скриншоты один на другой (красная линия и синие точки - старый график, серая линия и зелёные точки - новый), то видно, что уменьшение скорости находится в нескольких конкретных областях (настораживает кусок в районе 80% - 95%), а большая часть графика полностью совпадает:

[image: Наложение скриншотов - различия sda]

Поскольку основные сомнения вызывает конец диска, сделал замер по разделу `sda9` (замеры двухнедельной давности есть ещё и по всем разделам в отдельности). Обращаю внимание, что на первом скриншоте максимум шкалы скорости 180, а на втором 170, но максимумы по шкале времени одинаковы (50). На совмещённом скриншоте это учитывается.

[image: Старый скриншот sda9]

[image: Новый скриншот sda9]

[image: Наложение скриншотов - различия sda9]

#### Вопросы

- Следует ли рассматривать такие изменения просто как статистическую погрешность, или же они показывают ухудшение состояния?
- Какие вообще отклонения нормальны для статистической погрешности?
- О чём может свидетельствовать ухудшение производительности диска в области, находящейся ближе к его концу?
- Похоже ли это на снижение точности позиционирования головок?
- Каково состояние диска?
- Если с ним что-то случится, то что будет с загрузочной областью в наиболее вероятном варианте? Т. е. всё накроется одновременно, либо она будет среди полетевшего последним, либо первым?

PS: Во время обоих замеров диск не был примонтирован и по-другому не использовался.

Comment: Думаю, что на двух тестах сложно строить статистику и какую-нибудь теорию. Проведите тест еще N раз (с одинаковым перерывом в 2 недели).

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, в целом согласен, поэтому и надеялся, что известны какие-то стандартные погрешности, чтобы можно было с ними сравнить. А то замеры не просто так были сделаны.

Comment: Подобные исследования напоминают мне одну жалобу в Самсунг на стиральную машину. У человека в барабане было на две дырки меньше, чем в его соседки. Этим он объяснял более худшие качества машины и требовал ее заменить.

Comment: @KoVadim, а что не так? Это один и тот же диск, а не разные.

Comment: Да, это один и тот же диск. Но где гарантия, что Вы обеспечили одинаковые условия тестирования? Что было как минимум одно и тоже ядро и одна и таже фоновая активность?

Запустите эту утилиту раз десять-двадцать подряд и посравнивайте.  Будет подобная ситуация, но и в сторону улучшения. Но это же не значит, что Ваш диск начал излечиваться.

Comment: @KoVadim, поэтому первыми и стоят вопросы про статистическую погрешность. Ответ "погрешность в пределах 10% нормальна для таких замеров" вполне может быть правильным. Просто лично я не знаю, какая погрешность нормальна. В любом случае, кажется несколько странным, что изменения сосредоточены в конкретной области (но и в этом можно переубедить). Замеры сделаны в Linux Mint 17.3 в первом случае с флешки, во втором с жёсткого диска (но другого физического). С измеряемым диском обе системы никак не связаны и разделы с него не были примонтированы в момент замера.

Comment: Не знаю, как 10 процентов, но думаю, что 5 вполне оправдано. Если нужно больше - то лучше найти документацию на Ваш диск и тестировать согласно ей.

Comment: @KoVadim прав. Замерьте 10 раз подряд. Если замер двухнедельной давности будет близок к одному из этих, то с диском все в порядке. Иначе, вопрос остается открытым, поскольку в точности воспроизвести условия 2-х недельной давности вряд ли получится.

Comment: @Qwertiy: вас производительность интересует сама по себе, или вы переживаете, что диску хуже становится? Если вас беспокоит вопрос износа, то лучше ориентироваться на показания S.M.A.R.T. и прогресс их ухудшения.

Comment: @МАН69К, меня интересует факт ухудшения. Бекапы-то я сделал, но проблема в том, что в данный момент это единственный физический диск, на который можно установить винду без перепрошивки bios'а под uefi. Собственно, она на нём и установлена. А линукс установлен на 3TB-диске.

Comment: @МАН69К, в смарте есть кое-что интересное, но есть и то, чего я не хочу добавлять в вопрос. Критичных изменений за последнее время не замечено. Точнее, на графиках в Hard Disk Sentinel что-то есть, но я не уверен, на основании чего он их строит.

Comment: А через MHDD\Victoria винт прогонял?